# How to set nodejs debug mode don't listen 127.0.0.1

Tags: eclipse, node.js, remote-debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I want to remote debug the nodejs program in Eclipse. I start the node script with the debug option.

```
$node debug script.js
```

But I can't connect to the node in Eclispe. When I netstat the node's TCP port. I found that node only listen 127.0.0.1 in debug mode. So I can't connect it from different computer.
But I can't find any startup options that can change to listen to any address.
Anyone know to make it listen to any address to remote debug in other computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a great tut on debugging nodejs from eclipse](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/using-eclipse-as-node-applications-debugger). Note at the bottom there is a script the author uses to forward localhost:5858 to the remote server's 127.0.0.1. You could also just [use an SSH tunnel](http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html).

So, to summarize:

1. start your script with `node --debug app.js`
2. configure eclipse as if you were debugging locally
3. use the node_g script or configure an SSH tunnel
4. go on vacation now that your code is bug-free

Comment: I've tried 3 methods. First the script (which the tutorial invalidly says is not useful anymore) but it requires a local nodejs installation. Second I tried to use balance on my server, but it didn't work. Last I tried an SSH tunnel using putty. That just works great, I already use putty to start nodejs so it means I have no extra work with it. Also, it's what tunnels are for.

Answer (score 9):

if anyone else stumble upon this: you can set the node debug to any address as you set the port

```
node --debug=169.168.1.2:5858 app.js
```

if that would be the ip of your remote machine or even better to every machine

```
node --debug=0.0.0.0:5858 app.js
```

but please be aware that the 2nd option should only be used if you are debugging in your own private network as you open it up for everyone

Comment: Perfect, this is what I needed to connect to the application running in a docker container.

Comment: `--debug` is deprecate, now use `--inspect`

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do in linux Debian:

install balancer

`sudo apt-get install balance -y`

then create a route in balancer to reroute your 5858 port to 5859

`balance 5859 127.0.0.1:5858`

start your app

`node --debug app.js`

now you can access it from everywhere on port 5859

Answer (score 4):

I'm looking into V8 code that goes through deps/v8/src/debug-agent.* down to deps/v8/src/platform-posix.cpp (for linux) to POSIXSocket::Bind method and it can't seem to have any option about this (unless I'm missing something).

I bet you either hack it and recompile node or you'll need to build a small proxy beside your node process.

Answer (score 0):

to debug nodejs remotely over SSH session do:

```
1. install balance on Linux: https://balance.inlab.net/overview/
2. run the command: balance -df 8585 127.0.0.1:5858 > /tmp/balance.out 2>&1 &
3. ssh to your remote Linux box (tunnel will be created 8585 > 5858 > nodejs)
4. run your node script on server: node --debug-brk --nolazy ./myNodeApp.js
5. kick off debug session in WebStorm alt-d to port 8585
```

now you are remote debugging securely over SSH session